# Is it possible to show a mol structure from rdkit in a GUI?

Tags: pysimplegui, rdkit

The code I've in mind is quite simple (see below). The idea is that when the OK button is clicked the text filed is automatically upload with the relevant structural formula. Would someone help me?

`enter code here` import PySimpleGUI as sg
from rdkit import Chem

```
              # e.g. cysteine
              mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles("C([C@@H](C(=O)O)N)S")

              layout=[[sg.Text('Example', key='TEXT', enable_events=True)], [sg.Button('OK')]]

              window=sg.Window('', layout, finalize=True)

              def ok():
              window[f'TEXT'].update(mol)
              while True:
                 event, values = window.read()
                 if event=='OK':
                    ok()
                 if event==sg.WIN_CLOSED:
                    break
                 window.close()'''
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the question is, but try to view the molecules.

```py
from io import BytesIO
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import Draw
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def image_to_data(im):
    """
    Image object to bytes object.
    : Parameters
      im - Image object
    : Return
      bytes object.
    """
    with BytesIO() as output:
        im.save(output, format="PNG")
        data = output.getvalue()
    return data

mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles("C([C@@H](C(=O)O)N)S")
data = image_to_data(Draw.MolToImage(mol, returnPNG=True))

layout=[
    [sg.Image(data=data)],
    [sg.Button('OK')],
]

sg.Window('Title', layout).read(close=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you very much for your suggestion. Actually, thanks to it now what I had in mind works quite well.